# Grid "no_results" not working?

Tags: templates, grid

**Am I using `no_results` properly?** Even when the grid doesn't have any data, I cannot get the "N/A" to output in the templates:

```
{store_telephone_data limit="1" offset="0"}
    {if store_telephone_data:no_results}
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
    {/if}
    {if store_telephone_data:count == 1}
        <td>
            {store_telephone_data:store_telephone_number}
        </td>
        <td>
            {store_telephone_data:store_telephone_type limit="1" offset="0"}
                {store_telephone_data:store_telephone_type:title}
            {/store_telephone_data:store_telephone_type}                                    
        </td>
    {/if}
{/store_telephone_data}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `no_result` variable or condition for grid. Use [`total_rows`](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/grid.html#total-rows) instead.

```
{if store_telephone_data:total_rows >= 1}
    ...
{if:else}
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

The grid field doesn't provide a no_results tag. If you are using [search filters](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/grid.html#search-column-name) on the grid field total_rows will amount to a blank value due to the filters evaluating to true. There is an answer to a possible [workaround](https://expressionengine.com/forums/archive/topic/246910/no-results-variable-for-grid-field) but I see it as messy and either grid need to update their code or a small developed plugin could help.